# What is the benefit of Redis clustering on different hosts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

Let's say I have 3 instances of web app A running behind a load balancer (all on different machines).

Is there a benefit of running Redis on more than one instance?  If so, how do you achieve parity between more than one Redis instance?

I guess I'm curious of the pros/cons with such a setup.

The whole reason this question came up is wouldn't some of the benefits of using Redis in the first place be negated if you use more than one instance of a web app?  Interacting with Redis on a local machine seems like it would be much faster than pulling the data from in memory on instance A and then moving it over the network to Instance B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a benefit of running Redis on more than one instance?

Yes. There're at least three benefits.

1. Redis is single-threaded (in fact, it has more than one thread, but the most work is done in a single thread). With more than one instance, you can achieve better performance.
2. Redis stores data in memory, and the storage is limited to the size of a single machine's memory. In order to store more data, you can deploy more than one Redis instances on different machines, and each instance stores a different part of the whole data.
3. You can have a Redis master instance and its slave instance running on 2 different machines. If the machine that running master instance is down, the slave instance can still serves the requests.

> If so, how do you achieve parity between more than one Redis instance?

I'm not sure what do you mean by *parity*. Do you mean master-slave relationship? Redis can have a master with several slaves, and each slave can even has its own slaves (if I remember correctly).

> wouldn't some of the benefits of using Redis in the first place be negated if you use more than one instance of a web app? Interacting with Redis on a local machine seems like it would be much faster than pulling the data from in memory on instance A and then moving it over the network to Instance B.

If you deploy Redis instance and the web app instance on 2 different machines, you must make sure that the network between the 2 machines has **low latency**.

Comment: Great information.  When I say parity I mean is it possible to have 2 Redis instances remain identical.  So if you setup a master/slave.  How do you achieve data parity between the two.

Comment: Unfortunately, Redis's master-slave model is NOT strong consistency, and it can only support eventual consistency. That means, when you write some keys to the master, you CANNOT get these updates from the slave until the synchronization between master and slave finishes.